# Do you think i am selected for the job?

Tags: job-offer

i made an interview on May 18 2915, in May 22,2015 the HR person called ma and asked me questions and told me about the wor and working hours and disscussed the salary with me, then he said i will call you next Monday or tuesday but he didnt. 
on Wednedsday i sent him a follow up email and he replied that he will have an answer within two days.

do you think i am selected or this is made with all candidates and i have the same opportunity like all other candidates

Comment: see [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description it's impossible to give a definite general answer.

In my personal experience it means virtually nothing.  While it's possible that you were included in a narrow-downed list of candidates, there's no way of knowing.  I once was in "*we need just to interview one other candidate*" stage for weeks.

So the only prudent thing to do is just to go ahead with your job search.

**P.S.**

You tagged you question with`job offer`.  I hope you understand that you do not have a job offer at this time.

Comment: Today the two days period the HR said he get back to me ended, do you think i should follow up or just wait??

Comment: Unless I'm told "if you do not here from me by ... call me" I usually wait for some reasonable time (no more than a week).

Comment: @Laithishtaiwi While you are in the process of "just waiting" make sure you continue the job search as suggested. Even if you get an offer it is not finalized until both sides get it on paper and commit to it.